# Google Calendar How to get Date Object

Tags: java, date, calendar, format, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to display the events of a google calendar using the google calendar API in java.
But I don't have any idea on how to get the date (and time) of my events in a nice looking format. The only thing I can do is the following:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
Events events = service.events().list("primary")
        .setMaxResults(7)
        .setTimeMin(now)
        .setOrderBy("startTime")
        .setSingleEvents(true)
        .execute();
items = events.getItems();


items.get(0).getStart().getDateTime();
```

which leads to the following output:
2018-11-06T18:00:00.000+01:00

Any idea on how to get it e.g. as a Date Object?

Comment: What object type does the getDateTime(); function return? Isn't it already a DateObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Google API reference](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime) the type `DateTime` has a method `getValue()` which

> Returns the date/time value expressed as the number of milliseconds
>   since the Unix epoch.

To get an `java.util.Date` we can use this `long` value:

```
Date date = new Date(items.get(0).getStart().getDateTime().getValue());
```

But note that since Java 8 there is the java.time API. To get a `LocalDateTime` you can go on like that:

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(items.get(0).getStart().getDateTime().getTimeZoneShift() * 60);
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", offset);    
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zone);
```

To determine the appropriate `ZoneId` we use the method `getTimeZoneShift()` which

> Returns the time zone shift from UTC in minutes or 0 for date-only
>   value.

Since `ZoneId.ofOffset` takes  as second parameter a value in seconds, we have to convert the minutes returned by `getTimeZoneShift()` to seconds first.